# numba-TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend) non-precise type pyobject

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, opencv, numba

I am trying to run some code using numba. I have noticed that the code needs to be in the form of a function. I have the following code. It extracts frames (RGB images) from videos and appends (stores) it in a list. Please refer the follwing code

```py
#opencv 4
@jit(nopython=True)
def video_to_frames(col):
    frame_list = []
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture('/media/michael/extHDD/Kaggle/DeepFAke/DF_all/{}'.format(col_name[i]))
    while(cap.isOpened()):
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        if ret == False:
            break
            frame_list.append(frame) # list of all the frames in fake video
    cap.release()
    return frame_list
```

It runs within the following piece of code;

```py
#Main piece of code
first_for_loop = tqdm(range(0,100000,5))

for i in range(len(first_for_loop)):
    if str(df2['original'][i]).endswith(".mp4"):
        if len(video_to_frames(df2['original']))==len(video_to_frames(df2['fake_name'])): 
            d1 = diff(video_to_frames(df2['original']),video_to_frames(df2['fake_name'])) #diff is another function
            list_of_dis = list_of_distance(d1) #another function
            max_value = max(list_of_dis)
            max_index = list_of_dis.index(max_value)
            cv2.imwrite('/home/michael/DFDC_New/FakeTrain/frame_'+str(df2['fake_name'][i])[:-4]+'.jpg',
                        fake_frame_list[max_index])         
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

However, once I run this code I get an error when I run the **main piece of code**. Please find it below.

Output;

[image]

Would anybody be able to help me in this regard.

Thanks & Best Regards

Michael

Comment: Is Numba supposed to work with OpenCV in nopython mode? It only allows a limited set of Python, and works quite well with NumPy but not with every library

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply I am yet to go through the docs of numba. The code that have has a lot of loops and computations hence the thought of using numba with python code. Will let you know if there is a better way possible. Thanks & Best Regards